# How to initialize an associative array from an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

Given

```
 this.themes = [
    {
       name: 'Material Teal', 
       colors: {
          'primary': { default: [ 0,  150, 136], a100: [167, 255, 237], a200: [100, 255, 218], a400: [ 29, 233, 182], a700: [  0, 191, 165] },
          'accent' : { default: [103,  58, 183], a100: [179, 136, 255], a200: [124,  77, 255], a400: [101,  31, 255], a700: [ 98,   0, 234] },
          'warn'   : { default: [244,  67,  54], a100: [255, 138, 128], a200: [255,  82,  82], a400: [255,  23,  68], a700: [213,   0,   0] }
       }
    },
    ...
];
```

and

```
export class Theme {
   name: string;
   colors: { [intention: string]: { default: number[], a100: number[], a200: number[], a400: number[], a700: number[] } };
   constructor(name: string, colors: { [intention: string]: { default: number[], a100: number[], a200: number[], a400: number[], a700: number[] } }) {
      this.name = name;
      this.colors = colors;
   }
   ...
}
```

how do I pass in the `colors` part of the object? I thought

```
let theme = new Theme(theme.name, theme.colors);
```

would do the trick, but that gives me an error:

```
[ts] Argument of type '{ 'primary': { default: number[]; a100: number[]; a200: number[]; a400: number[]; a700: number[];...' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [intention: string]: { default: number[]; a100: number[]; a200: number[]; a400: number[]; a700:...'.

Index signature is missing in type '{ 'primary': { default: number[]; a100: number[]; a200: number[]; a400: number[]; a700: number[];...'.
```

What is an index signature and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the compiler doesn't understand that `this.themes` is of the type:

```
{
    name: string;
    colors: { [name: string]: {
        default: number[];
        a100: number[];
        a200: number[];
        a400: number[];
        a700: number[];
    }
}
```

All you need to do is specify the type, so something like this:

```
interface ThemeColor {
    default: number[];
    a100: number[];
    a200: number[];
    a400: number[];
    a700: number[];
}

interface ThemeColors {
    [name: string]: ThemeColor;
}

interface Theme {
    name: string;
    colors: ThemeColors;
}

let themes: Theme[] = [
    {
       name: 'Material Teal', 
       colors: {
          'primary': { default: [ 0,  150, 136], a100: [167, 255, 237], a200: [100, 255, 218], a400: [ 29, 233, 182], a700: [  0, 191, 165] },
          'accent' : { default: [103,  58, 183], a100: [179, 136, 255], a200: [124,  77, 255], a400: [101,  31, 255], a700: [ 98,   0, 234] },
          'warn'   : { default: [244,  67,  54], a100: [255, 138, 128], a200: [255,  82,  82], a400: [255,  23,  68], a700: [213,   0,   0] }
       }
    }
];

export class ThemeClass {
   name: string;
   colors: ThemeColors;

   constructor(data: Theme) {
      this.name = data.name;
      this.colors = data.colors;
   }
}

new ThemeClass(themes[0]);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ThemeColor%20%7B%0D%0A%09default%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09a100%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09a200%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09a400%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09a700%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ThemeColors%20%7B%0D%0A%09%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ThemeColor%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Theme%20%7B%0D%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09colors%3A%20ThemeColors%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20themes%3A%20Theme%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Material%20Teal'%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20colors%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'primary'%3A%20%7B%20default%3A%20%5B%200%2C%20%20150%2C%20136%5D%2C%20a100%3A%20%5B167%2C%20255%2C%20237%5D%2C%20a200%3A%20%5B100%2C%20255%2C%20218%5D%2C%20a400%3A%20%5B%2029%2C%20233%2C%20182%5D%2C%20a700%3A%20%5B%20%200%2C%20191%2C%20165%5D%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'accent'%20%3A%20%7B%20default%3A%20%5B103%2C%20%2058%2C%20183%5D%2C%20a100%3A%20%5B179%2C%20136%2C%20255%5D%2C%20a200%3A%20%5B124%2C%20%2077%2C%20255%5D%2C%20a400%3A%20%5B101%2C%20%2031%2C%20255%5D%2C%20a700%3A%20%5B%2098%2C%20%20%200%2C%20234%5D%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'warn'%20%20%20%3A%20%7B%20default%3A%20%5B244%2C%20%2067%2C%20%2054%5D%2C%20a100%3A%20%5B255%2C%20138%2C%20128%5D%2C%20a200%3A%20%5B255%2C%20%2082%2C%20%2082%5D%2C%20a400%3A%20%5B255%2C%20%2023%2C%20%2068%5D%2C%20a700%3A%20%5B213%2C%20%20%200%2C%20%20%200%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20ThemeClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20colors%3A%20ThemeColors%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20constructor(data%3A%20Theme)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20data.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.colors%20%3D%20data.colors%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20ThemeClass(themes%5B0%5D)%3B%0D%0A))

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `[intention: string]` by `'primary'`, like that :

```
export class Theme {
   name: string;
   colors: { 'primary': { default: number[], a100: number[], a200: number[], a400: number[], a700: number[] } };
   constructor(name: string, colors: { 'primary': { default: number[], a100: number[], a200: number[], a400: number[], a700: number[] } }) {
      this.name = name;
      this.colors = colors;
   }
   ...
}
```

And WARNING ! You are defining `theme` with the `let` operator but this variable already exists !